# Does a type safe language needs to be statically typed?

Tags: php, programming-languages, type-safety, dynamic-typing, static-typing

I am trying to understand what it means for a language to be type-safe. In a dynamically typed language, the type checking is performed at run time, so for example if I run the following PHP code:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{ 
}

// Create a MyClass instance
$mc = new MyClass();

// Create an int variable
$i = 1234;

// Add $mc and $i
$result = $mc + $i;
?>
```

I will get an error because the `+ operator` does not support the `MyClass` data type. So basically the type checking was performed at run time.

Does type safety means that type checking is performed regardless if it is performed at compile time or at run time, or does it mean that type checking must be performed only at compile time and so each variable must be given a data type explicitly (like C, Pascal, Java, etc.).

Comment: For this particular situation, there is some kind of type safety, but there's none if you say `function x() { $i = 0; if (true) { $i = "bla"; } return $i; }` ...

Comment: btw. your exmaple will result in 1235 so there's no safety there as well

Comment: @Royal Bg If a language performs type checking at run time and halt the program if a type error was found, is such a language called type safe language?

Comment: Most probably not. In some papers you might find these language as limited type safe languages or type safe in a limited context. For me, there's no type safety, if you can hide it in an `if()` block

Comment: C is not entirely typesafe. If it was, it wouldn't have as much undefined behavior as it does. C# is not necessarily statically, strongly typed, but it _is_ considered typesafe. But then again, it needn't be, if you don't want it to be. Java was designed to be typesafe, but still has a series of exceptions that you have to throw/handle in case the type system lets you down (`BigDecimal.divide`, `NullPointerException`, ...)

Answer (score 6):

"Type safe" usually means "memory type safe", that is, you can't treat the memory that contains one type as if it was another type.

By this definition, most higher-level languages, including dynamically typed languages, are type safe, because any attempt to use a type incorrectly is guaranteed to cause an error (compile-time or run-time) in them.

So, type safety is mostly an issue for low-level languages, especially C and C++. And those issues often involve pointers or casting (e.g. `reinterpret_cast` in C++).

C# is an interesting case that lies between the two groups: it is type safe by default, but you can turn off type safety for parts of your code using the `unsafe` keyword (usually for performance or interop reasons).

---

But if you combine type safety with static typing, it doesn't necessarily mean having to write types. Many static type-safe languages, especially functional ones, or those inspired by them, use [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference). This means that the compiler can figure out the type of a variable by itself, based on what's assigned to it, so you don't have to type it. Examples of this are the `auto` keyword in C++ and `var` in C#.

Comment: Type safety is not an issue, as it prevents you from making mistakes and helps you to make sure, you know what you're doing (PHP is like cooking with ingredients you don't know about). And on my personal opinion type inference in type safe languages is not good, as it allows you to lose the overview about the variables types to easy. Huh, you don't? Then the person who have to expand or change your code block decades later.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. Python is an example of a dynamically but strongly typed language:

```
>>> "foo" + 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Haxe is an example of a compile-time type-safe language, which still doesn't require types to be declared statically:

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        trace(10 * Test.some());
    }

    static function some() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

> Build failure
> Test.hx:3: characters 19-30 : String should be Int
```

This is done with [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference).

Comment: How can Haxe knows the data type of a variable at compile type if they are not statically declared, I can just change the data type inside of an `if` block preventing Haxe to know what the data type will be at compile time.

Comment: @Steve: at some point, you have to assign something to a var, and this is where Haxe infers its type. You can also declare a variable as dynamic, just like in Python. See http://old.haxe.org/ref/type_infer

Comment: What I meant was if Haxe performed type checking at compile time, and it also supports creating variables without explicitly specifying their data type, this means I can make an if block that changes the data type of a variable at run time, and later this variable is used in a statement that does not support this newly changed data type. For example: var i = 123; if (something) i = new MyClass(); var result = i + otherVariable;

Comment: So it's like variables are statically declared but without actually specifying the data type!

Comment: In that case I don't think that this is a correct statement: "compile-time type-safe language, which still doesn't require types to be declared statically", I don't think that a compile-time type-safe language can allow the change of a data type at run time.

Comment: @Steve: They can, sort of: C++ has special casts, for example (`reinterpret_cast`, `dynamic_cast` and `static_cast`). C# also has dynamic typing (`var foo = 123;` is the same as `int foo = 123;`), and C++11's `auto` keyword also allows static declarations without specifying the actual type. In C, types only exist during compile time, so you can -sort of- change the data type of a variable during runtime quite easily: `int i = 20; some_func_expecting_char_ptr(&i);` <-- in the function, `i` will be used as `char *`, a `union` could be used, too